# Jekyll Bootstrap based blog - Expire headers?

Tags: jekyll, http-caching, github-pages, cache-invalidation

I have a Jekyll bootstrap based blog hosted on Github pages.

My problem is: Every time I change something on my web page, I have to forcefully reload the page (CTRL + R) to see the changes.

Jekyll or my browser does not seem to realize that there is a newer version available to send out.

How can I configure Jekyll to better handle this?

Comment: Chances are that Github Pages is sending out aggressive caching headers, telling the browser not to check for an updated version of the resource until a certain time.

Comment: So there is no possibility to circumvent this with Github Pages?

Comment: You'll need to ask them about their caching practices.

Comment: Hey @SebastianHoitz did you solve this? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: I've also asked them about this, but to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of jekyl plugins to handle assets cache busting.

https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets/

http://matthodan.com/2012/11/22/jekyll-asset-pipeline.html

I tried jekyll-assets and it's pretty nice as it manage all kind of assets with an md5 version number.

Before I use to append a string to my css links at compilation time.

```
<link href="{{ ASSET_PATH }}/css/global.css?{{ site.time | date:'%Y%m%d%U%H%N%S' }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Question is not about assets, it's about html cache.

Comment: yop but this plugin add cache busting strings, that's why I answered here. my bad :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add these meta tags to your html to disable browser caching for your pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to bypass the cache on static resources you could change the name of the file each time you push it. This will make the browser get the new resource since it won't know anything about a file with a new name.

For example:

Old file name: `project.css`
New file name: `projectv01.css`

Or whatever you would like.

Comment: The referring page would have to be renamed as well which would break the user experience completely. Instead of index.html it would have to be index01.html :).  Otherwise the cache will serve the index.html that points to project.css rather than projectv01.css.  Using javascript to add ?cache=random to every content url is A solution.. but a horrible bad solution.